# can you add a calendar in a node.js/express mongoose app that acts as a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, calendar

I am a beginner trying to work on a todo node.js/express mongoose app. I am trying to have a calendar on the home page that enables the user to click on any given date to explore the todos list that he has added. I am kinda stuck right now, wanted to see if I can use this calendar as another model/database that is linked with the todos model/database
so far I am thinking I would need to have a calendar on the home page, but not sure if I can set it as a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't think you need to do that. You can just build a calendar in the frontend, and assign dates to the tasks/todos. Then you can take tasks from the array and place it on the calendar.

Feel free to ask if you need more clarification

Comment: would you elaborate more ?